Connect Square Space domain to Google Cloud Bucket
I follow the insturction in this question and although everything seem to be correct, my site still does not connect, why?  The domain is exactly the same in DNS and bucket name.

Hitting my website directly does work and it's public:

Bucket name is exactly the same as entered:

Using mxtoolbox I get this error:

The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.***datamining.com'
(http://www.***datamining.com)

Directly going to the site get this error:


Google documents the process more definitively than the stack overflow answer. It appears that you've verified the domain ownership using Google Search Console. Your DNS record appears correct. How long ago did you update the Squarespace records? DNS propagation is usually ~minutes but it's possible it could take longer. Obfuscating your intended public domain name is unnecessary and inhibits our ability to verify your DNS records.
